# iPad workspaces

Tags: ipad

Is there an app that allows one to create "workspaces" on the iPad?

A workspace is essentially a particular set of open documents/windows that can be saved and reopened later.

This allows you to forget "setting up" by opening apps and loading documents every time, and makes the experience more task-oriented.  Workspaces could easily make working on the iPad 10 times more productive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no.

However, so long as you do not run the thing totally flat, and assuming that all apps you use are compiled to use the features available like auto-resume and saved states etc, there is no reason why once you have got the iPad into the configuration you like, it won;t stay that way untless you change it.  Opening Pages or iPod or Notes should always start where you left it.  But from a clean start, or to refresh your entire app status across multiple apps to a saved state is not possible as a single operation.

Comment: True, the iPad comes by default slightly more workspace-oriented than a PC in that respect.  BUT that disregards the far more important part of the question: We need to be able to SAVE workspaces and open them up by name later to resume the task we were working on.

Comment: If you have specific feedback about new features, submit it to Apple. Your idea is solid, but at the end of the day, I think would introduce too much complexity into iOS.  Especially when most apps can be opened and configured pretty quickly anyways. http://www.apple.com/feedback/

Comment: No sure about the "we", but you certainly have that requirement, unfortunately it's still not possible even if you think if should be made possible, although Chris's comments about feedback are a timely reminder that feeding back to Apple is one way of getting your voice heard.